# Count the quantity of combinations in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have been working with the macro below, posted earlier, but cannot introduce another column? I have four columns of data and would like to know how many times three numbers appear in any order within the data set.  I am still learning so any help would be appreciated.

For instance:

```
  1  16  13  43
  1  19  45  58
  1  69  58   3
 13  16  63   1
  6  34  33  59
  6  45  19  58
  6  43  48  50
```

Answers

```
 13, 16,  1 = 2
 45, 58, 19 = 2
```

etc...

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetCombinations()
    Dim sheet1, sheet2 As Worksheet
    Set sheet1 = Worksheets(1)
    Set sheet2 = Worksheets(2)

    Dim sStartColumn As String
    Dim iTopRow As Long
    Dim sEndColumn As String
    Dim iBottomRow As Long

    sStartColumn = "A"
    iTopRow = 1
    sEndColumn = "E"
    iBottomRow = sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim sRange1 As String
    sRange1 = sStartColumn & CStr(iTopRow) & ":" & sEndColumn & CStr(iBottomRow)

    Set Rng = sheet1.Range(sRange1)
    Rng.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
         Key2:=Range("B2"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
         Orientation:=xlSortColumns, Header:=xlYes

    Dim i, j As Integer
    j = 2
    For i = 2 To iBottomRow
        If sheet1.Cells(i, 4) Then
            sheet2.Cells(j, 1) = sheet1.Cells(i, 1)
            sheet2.Cells(j, 2) = sheet1.Cells(i, 2)
            sheet2.Cells(j, 3) = sheet1.Cells(i, 5)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am making two assumptions here:

1. Each number the row is unique (i.e. you do not duplicate a number in the same row)
2. The numbers are within a defined range (e.g. 1 to MaxNum) and that MaxNum is a reasonable size (e.g. < 96)

For each row, you can store the numbers as truth values in a bit string (e.g. for your first row (1,16,13,43), bits 1, 16, 13 and 43 would be set to "1" and the remaining elements in the bit string would be set to "0". For each row the bit string would be exactly the same length (hence the assumption of a known MaxNum).  If assumption (1) is falsified, the solution I describe here will not work (at least not without some major modification).

You can then iterate through each string to do a comparison and store that comparison somehow

```
For I = 1 to numString - 1
  for J = I+1 to numString
    ' Do something
  Next J
Next I
```

The `'do something` part is using bitwise operators (simply `and` and you want to count the number of `true` results to see if you get three or more). If your numbers were small (i.e. <32) you could use built in functions, but the numbers in your examples are much larger. This opens two options - split the overall bit string into a number of smaller (e.g. 32 bit) values and iterate over these, or build your own simple function for an `and` result (as this is the only Boolean function that you require.

In my mind, the simplest way to get results is to create a collection of valid bit strings (i.e. for each row you would get a set of strings(*) that contain three `true/'1'` bits, or a single string that is all `'0'`), order these string so you can group like strings and then count the number of strings in each group along with a decoded title for the three numbers in each string.

(*) if you have (e.g.) 4 numbers that match in a row there are multiple ways you can get three numbers from those four numbers. These means that for some rows you will have multiple results.

The advantage of the method I have described above is that it is now scalable. You can have three columns, four columns, five columns etc. You can also change the validity rule to pick up three matching numbers, four matching numbers etc. quite easily.

I have not provided any examples of actual coding here. While there are a number of interesting concepts involved (string manipulation if you actually use a string to store the 'bits', Boolean operations, sorting and grouping), each one of these is represented by suitable tutorials on the web. In addition, I am sure that these concepts have individually been covered within Stack Exchange.